# Error in copy-pasted code: type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#

When trying to implement the find route between two points, I used [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd80b9/finding-route-between-two-locations-in-windows-phone-7-using/), but it produces an  error :

> The type or namespace name 'findroute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using findroute.geocodeservice;
  private void Geocode(string strAddress, int waypointIndex)
    {
        // Here we create the service variable and set the callback method using the GeocodeCompleted property.
        findroute.geocodeservice.GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new findroute.geocodeservice.GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        geocodeService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<findroute.geocodeservice.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted);
        // Here we Set the credentials and the geocode query,which could be an address or location.
        findroute.geocodeservice.GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new findroute.geocodeservice.GeocodeRequest();
        geocodeRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
        geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = ((ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider)map1.CredentialsProvider).ApplicationId;
        geocodeRequest.Query = strAddress;
        // Now Making the asynchronous Geocode request, using the 'waypoint index' as
        //   the user state to track this request and allow it to be identified when the response is returned.
        geocodeService.GeocodeAsync(geocodeRequest, waypointIndex);
    }
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: It sounds like the core namespace of the project he's creating. Try your core namespace instead of 'findroute'.

Comment: 100% true .. thnx ... i feel so stubbed .. ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Did you follow this bit of the instructions?

> - Go to Solution Explorer
> - Also add a service reference--> Right click on reference
> - Add service reference
> - In the address bar type- `http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc/mex`. This is to use the Route related classes in the application. Name this service reference as `routeservice`.
> - Add another service reference `http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc/mex`. This is to use the Geocode related classes in the application. Name this service reference as `geocodeservice`.

It's possible that the *actual* name given was `findroute.routeservice` instead of just `routeservice`, but that's basically what it's looking for - adjust your code accordingly with whatever name you've used.

Comment: i flow the article step by step

Comment: and implement the service references ... but still have this error ... and i really need some help .. cause it's important to my graduation project ... please if have any smiler articles like this that i can use ... thanx .. ^_^